# Zookeeper client cannot rmr /brokers/topics/MY_TOPIC

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to remove a Kafka topic with 8 partitions and 2 replications. First I delete that topic using kafka-topic.sh --delete command. Then I used zkCli.sh -server slave1.....slave3, and rmr /brokers/topics/MY_TOPIC.

However I still see that topic in /brokers/topics/. And I tried restart Kafka, everything still the same.

Btw, topic with 1 partition and 1 replica can be deleted successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set server properties to enable delete of kafka topic

Add line mentioned below in service.properties

```
delete.topic.enable = true
```

If you removing manually using rmr /brokers/topics/MY_topic then you also need to remove topic related metadata from other nodes in zookeeper ex- consumer information about that topic. Also need to remove kafka topic director on kafka server.

It is cleaner to enable topic delete property and execute kafka-topics.sh --delete